# Array/list of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, listofitems

How can I retrive a numbers from array or list so I can use them as part of computation such as following :

```
\def\MaxValueArray{9220,1024,0.95,162.22}
 \foreach \valBS  [count=\k] in {4089,512,0.65,125.85}{
    \path (3*\A:\k) node[right,font=\tiny] {\k*\valBS/MaxValueArray[\k]};
```

I was not able to do that is there anyway I can retrieve the value from array by using an index to fetch it.

Comment: Please provide a simple but full minimum working example (MWE), not just a code snippet.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: LaTeX itself does not have an array as data structure. To really access an item in a comma-separate list the context is important. expl3 provides an easy way, but please provide more context (a MWE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listofitems` package has array capability.

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\usepackage{tikz,listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\A{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\readlist\MaxValueArray{9220,1024,0.95,162.22}
 \foreach \valBS  [count=\k] in {4089,512,0.65,125.85}{
    \path (3*\A:\k) node[right,font=\tiny] {\k*\valBS/\MaxValueArray[\k]}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

To evaluate the result (comment from OP), perhaps this:

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\usepackage{tikz,listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\A{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\readlist\MaxValueArray{9220,1024,0.95,162.22}
\readlist\valBS{4089,512,0.65,125.85}
 \foreachitem \k \in \valBS{
    \path (3*\A:\kcnt) node[right,font=\tiny] {
      \pgfmathparse{\kcnt*\k/\MaxValueArray[\kcnt]} \pgfmathresult};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**NATIVE `listofitems` LOOPING**

The same (former) result could be obtained with `listofitem`'s own looping capability:

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\usepackage{tikz,listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\A{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\readlist\MaxValueArray{9220,1024,0.95,162.22}
\readlist\valBS{4089,512,0.65,125.85}
 \foreachitem \k \in \valBS{
    \path (3*\A:\kcnt) node[right,font=\tiny] {\kcnt*\k/\MaxValueArray[\kcnt]};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but I would like to have the result of the calculation then printing the result I used {\pgfmathparse \kcnt*\k/\MaxValueArray[\kcnt]\pgfmathresult} but still print exactly the same as your result

Comment: @AlKharusi That is why you need to add an MWE to your question, instead of a code snippet.  The MWE should be minimal, but contain all the vital bits of information/coding relevant to the question.  For me, who does not know `pgf` nor `tikz` except in the most primitive way, having you provide the example code is vital for me to proceed.

Comment: @AlKharusi Please see my update, to see if it is what you were hoping for.

Comment: Yes that solve my problem many thanks Steven and sorry for any inconvenient I am just new here ...I appreciate your prompt response and clear answer.

Comment: @AlKharusi You are welcome.  If this is the best of the (possibly several) answers that may be provided, you should choose the best answer and click the check mark to the left of the answer to "accept" it.  That will tell other readers which answer (if any) solved your issue.